# SQL query for key value table with 1:n relation

Tags: sql

I have a table in which I want to store images. Each image has arbitrary properties that I want to store in a key-value table.

The table structure looks like this

| id | fk_picture_id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | camera | iphone |
| 2 | 1 | year | 2001 |
| 3 | 1 | country | Germany |
| 4 | 2 | camera | iphone |
| 5 | 2 | year | 2020 |
| 6 | 2 | country | United States |

Now I want a query to find all pictures made by an iphone I could to something like this

```sql
select
    fk_picture_id
from
    my_table
where
    key = 'camera'
    and
    value = 'iphone';
```

This works without any problems. But as soon as I want to add another key to my query I am get stucked. Lets say, I want all pictures made by an iPhone in the year 2020, I can not do something like

```sql
select
    distinct(fk_picture_id)
from
    my_table
where
    (
        key = 'camera'
        and
        value = 'iphone'
    )
    or
    (
        key = 'year'
        and
        value = '2020'
    )
```

...because this selects the id 1, 4 and 5.

At the end I might have 20 - 30 different criteria to look for, so I don't think some sub-selects would work at the end.

I'm still in the design phase, which means I can still adjust the data model as well. But I can't think of any way to do this in a reasonable way - except to include the individual properties as columns in my main table.

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. `select distinct` returns distinct _rows_. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `select distinct fk_picture_id from ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: The word "relation" [does not mean what you think it means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045744/what-is-a-relation-in-database-terminology).

Comment: What you've posted is an example of the EAV Anti-Pattern, which is why you're running into problems. You need to redesign your database if you want to do things properly. I doubt you really _absolutely need_ an EAV table. Modern RDBMS support _sparse tables_ which are ideal for situations like these. Don't be afraid of `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: I found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954934/how-to-query-data-based-on-multiple-tags-in-sql/38955049 - last Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found - thanks to this article
[How to query data based on multiple 'tags' in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954934/how-to-query-data-based-on-multiple-tags-in-sql/38955049)

is that I made some changes to the database model

**picture**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Picture 1 |
| 2 | Picture 2 |

And then I created a table for the tags

**tag**

| id | tag |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Germany |
| 101 | IPhone |
| 102 | United States |

And the cross table

**picture_tag**

| fk_picture_id | fk_tag_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 101 |
| 2 | 101 |
| 2 | 102 |

For a better understanding of the datasets

| Picture | Tagname |
| --- | --- |
| Picture 1 | Germany & Iphone |
| Picture 2 | United States & IPhone |

Now I can use the following statement

```
SELECT *
  FROM picture
  INNER JOIN (
   SELECT fk_picture_id
   FROM picture_tag
   WHERE fk_tag_id IN (100, 101)
   GROUP BY fk_picture_id
   HAVING COUNT(fk_tag_id) = 2
  ) AS picture_tag
 ON picture.id = picture_tag.fk_picture_id;
```

The only thing I need to do before the query is to collect the IDs of the tags I want to search for and put the number of tags in the having count statement.

If someone needs the example data, here are the sql statements for the tables and data

```
 create table picture (
   id integer,
   name char(100)
 );

 create table tag (
  id integer,
  tag char(100)
 );

 create table picture_tag (
  fk_picture_id integer,
  fk_tag_id integer
 );

 insert into picture values (1, 'Picture 1');
 insert into picture values (2, 'Picture 2');

 insert into tag values (100, 'Germay');
 insert into tag values (101, 'iphone');
 insert into tag values (102, 'United States');

 insert into picture_tag values (1, 100);
 insert into picture_tag values (1, 101);
 insert into picture_tag values (2, 101);
 insert into picture_tag values (2, 102);
```

Answer (score 1):

A pattern you can consider here is to build a table of search parameters, then simply join this to your target table.

You would first create a temporary table with *key* and *value* columns then insert into it the search criteria values, any number of values you wish.

Using a CTE in place of a temporary table might look like:

```
with s as (
    select 'camera' key, 'iphone' value
    union all
    select 'year', '2020'
)
select distinct t.fk_picture_id
from s
join t on t.key=s.key and t.value=s.value
```

Comment: Would it make any differences in the complexity, if I remove the key column at all? So I would do something like "tagging" an image with different tags? I could create a tag table with all available tags and a cross table between image and tag, but I am not sure if that helps me for the searching process