# Access: Updatable join query with 2 primary key fields that are both also foreign keys

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

In MS Access, I am trying to implement a many-to-many table that will store 2-way relationships, similar to [Association between two entries in SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931880/association-between-two-entries-in-sql-table). This table stores info such as "Person A and Person B are coworkers" "C and D are friends", etc. The table is like this:

### ConstitRelationships

- *LeftId* (number, primary key, foreign key to Constituents.ConstitId)
- *RightId* (number, primary key, foreign key to Constituents.ConstitId)
- *Description* (text)

Note that the primary key is a composite of the two Id fields.
Also the table has constraints:

```
[LeftId]<>[RightId] AND [LeftId]<[RightId]
```

The table is working ok in my Access project, except that I cannot figure out how to make an **updateable** query that I want to use as a datasheet subform so users can easily add/delete records and change the descriptions. I currently have a non-updatable query:

```
SELECT Constituents.ConstituentId, Constituents.FirstName,
Constituents.MiddleName, Constituents.LastName, 
ConstitRelationships.Description, ConstitRelationships.LeftId, 
ConstitRelationships.RightId
FROM ConstitRelationships INNER JOIN Constituents ON 
(Constituents.ConstituentId =
ConstitRelationships.RightId) OR (Constituents.ConstituentId = 
ConstitRelationships.LeftId);
```

If I ignore the possibility that the constituentId I want is in the leftId column, I can do this, which *is* updatable. So the `OR` condition in the inner join above is what's messing it up.

```
SELECT Constituents.ConstituentId, Constituents.FirstName,
  Constituents.MiddleName, Constituents.LastName, 
  ConstitRelationships.Description, ConstitRelationships.LeftId, 
  ConstitRelationships.RightId
FROM ConstitRelationships INNER JOIN Constituents ON 
  (Constituents.ConstituentId =
  ConstitRelationships.RightId) ;
```

I also tried this wacky iif thing to collapse the two LeftId and RightId fields into FriendId, but it was not updateable either.

```
SELECT Constituents.ConstituentId, Constituents.FirstName, 
Constituents.MiddleName,
Constituents.LastName, subQ.Description
FROM Constituents
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Description, Iif([Forms]![Constituents Form]![ConstituentId] <>
  ConstitRelationships.LeftId, ConstitRelationships.LeftId, 
  ConstitRelationships.RightId) AS FriendId
FROM ConstitRelationships
WHERE ([Forms]![Constituents Form]![ConstituentId] = 
  ConstitRelationships.RightId)
  OR ([Forms]![Constituents Form]![ConstituentId] = 
  ConstitRelationships.LeftId)
) subQ
ON (subQ.FriendId = Constituents.ConstituentId)
;
```

**How can I make an updatable query on ConstitRelationships, including a JOIN with the Constituent.FirstName MiddleName LastName fields?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that is not possible. Because you use joins in your query over three tables it is not updatable. There is no way around this.

Here some detailed information about the topic: http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html

As mentioned in the linked article one possible solution and in my opinion best solution for you would be the temporary table. It is a load of work compared to the easy "bind-form-to-a-query"-approach but it works best.

The alternative would be to alter your datascheme in that way that you do not need joins. But then denormalized data and duplicates would go rampage which makes the temporary table a favorable choice.

Comment: I read the link, but I'm not sure how a temporary table would work. If users make changes (updates & deletes) to the temporary table, how would those changes get committed back to ConstitRelationships?

Comment: You have to write these procedures yourself. For example on the AfterUpdate_Event you execute an update query that saves the fields to the original table. That's what I meant with "load of work".